# visualize the point cloud .obj file

Tags: cloud, point, open3d, visualize

I have the error when visualizing the point cloud by using open3d.

My code is

import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

if **name** == "**main**":

```
print("Load a ply point cloud, print it, and render it")
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(r"D:\1. PSM 2020\TRY\ayuu\pointnet-master\Area_6_conferenceRoom_1_pred.obj")
print(pcd)
print(np.asarray(pcd.points))
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```

And the error said that my file do not have point cloud

runfile('D:/1. PSM 2020/TRY/ayuu/pointnet-master/sem_seg/TRY2.py', wdir='D:/1. PSM 2020/TRY/ayuu/pointnet-master/sem_seg')
Load a ply point cloud, print it, and render it
[Open3D WARNING] Read geometry::PointCloud failed: unknown file extension for D:\1. PSM 2020\TRY\ayuu\pointnet-master\Area_6_conferenceRoom_1_pred.obj (format: auto).
PointCloud with 0 points.
[]

But, if I visualize the point cloud using online 3d viewer, it will show the result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWmHN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `read_triangle_mesh` instead of `read_point_cloud` for reading an obj file. See http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.9.0/tutorial/Basic/file_io.html for an example.